# Mongoose: selecting all fields in a query (without knowing them at design-time) after having defined select: false in the schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoosejs to connect with MongoDB.

Consider the following contrived example of a schema:

```
var factSchema= new Schema({
    facts:  { type:[require('./fact')], select:false}
   ,roles: {type: [String], required: true, index: {unique: false}}
   ,c: {type:  {}, default: {}}  //all calculated stuff based on facts
}
```

Which explicitly states that when normally querying 'factSchema' the actual 'facts' aren't queried. Only after explicitly doing a select for 'facts' can I make sure those are included. I.e:

```
 //factModel is a model derived from factSchema
 factModel.findOne({_id:input.id})
    .select(["facts","roles","c"]).exec(function(err,result){//do something});
```

This works in this trivial case. 
However I've subclassed factSchema (info on how: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/mongoose-orm/INHERIT/mongoose-orm/aeqGRRnpFvg/lbfIA54hiwYJ ) and I want to query all fields of a specific subclass, but it's only known at runtime which subclass I'm querying. In other words I can't explicitly specify the fields that I want to be returned.

How would I go about this?

A possible solution seems to be (?) that I can get to all the defined fields of a schema by doing `subclassedSchema.paths` where `subclassedSchema` is a subclass of `factSchema` .

This works, but can I trust this to be stable under future releases? Any better, less hackish way to tackle this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no better method in the 2.x branch. Schema.paths is not changing in 3.x either so its safe to do this for the foreseeable future.

3.x has new `select` syntax which allows for simply calling `factModel.findOne(..).select('+facts').exec(callback)` to achieve the desired result.